# Why do 3 span4 bootstrap divs push the third to a new line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I thought bootstrap was based on a 12 column grid system. But the following code:

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="example-box span4">Example Text</div>
       <div class="example-box span4">Example Text</div>
       <div class="example-box span4">Example Text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

always pushes the last div down to the next line while keeping the other two on the same line. Am I missing something here? Removing the margin-right of the final box does not seem to work either.

Comment: Under normal use, it should work as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/A9zVe/ Do you have any custom CSS that may affect it? Such as a `margin-right` since `span*` typically only have `margin-left`?

Comment: check your `example-box` css make sure you are not using and border or anything else that might effect the width ... for correct usage see the answer below by @robyaw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's likely your `example-box` class contains box-model properties that are causing the Bootstrap model to break. The most likely solution to this is to use inner `div` elements, onto which you apply your custom CSS class(es), like so:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="span4">
          <div class="example-box">Example Text</div>
      </div>
      <div class="span4">
          <div class="example-box">Example Text</div>
      </div>
      <div class="span4">
          <div class="example-box">Example Text</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're added padding or borders to any of those span4's, that will cause this to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't have the css reset in your code? That could cause it to push the last div to the next line. Just a thought.